# SQL Statement Not failing, but not inserting

Tags: sql

ASP.NET 2.0, SQL 2005. I have a very basic insert statement. I enter all the data into the app and step through. No errors are rasied in the app or the stored proc. Yet, when I go to check out the table, no record was inserted. Is there some sort of quirk or bug in SQL server I am unaware of? I have tried ExecuteScalar & ExecuteNonQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to commit your transaction.

Answer (score 4):

Can it be that you open a transaction and never `Commit` one? Remember that

```
using(var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
{
    // Code
}
```

does not commit it, but rather rolls back the whole thing. You have to explicitly invoke `transaction.Commit()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had (have) this problem on a website of mine written in PHP. If you are trying to insert a string are you sure you have escaped all necessary characters? Using a single quote in something like don't, won't, or aren't needs to be escaped!

Comment: You shouldn't be concatentating strings together to build up a query anyway.  Properly parameeterised query won't have this problem.